# Simple way to check how many rows I have in my database

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I'm connected to a database through the `SqlConnection` class. Is there any simple why to check how many rows are in the database or do I have to create a `SqlDataReader` and increment till the last row in it ?

Comment: You mean rows in a table ?

Comment: Yes, exactly rows in the table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume *"rows in the database"* actually means *"rows in the table"*.

You should use [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [`SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
int rowCount = 0;
using(var con = new SqlConnection(connectionsString))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.TableName", con))
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        rowCount = (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    } catch (Exception ex)
    { 
        // log this exception or do something else useful, otherwise it's better to...
        throw;
    }
}
```